# Getting syntax error "E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):3:0" while inserting into Collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying MongoDB and while inserting into collection, I am getting error

> E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):3:0

**Code**:

```
db.bands.insert({
... Name: "Imagine Dragons"
... Event : [
... {
... Event : "Liberty State Park, 4th Sept",
... Year : 2019
... Genre : "Rock"
... },
... {
... Event : " Jersey City, 6th Oct",
... Year : 2019
... Genre : " Rock"
... }
... ]
... })
```

How to interpret this: @(shell):3:0? Trying coding for the first time.

Comment: There should be comma (`,`) after each field's value. See some [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.insert/index.html#examples) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for the input. It got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You missed, after value pairs for some. Below is the corrected code.

```
> db.bands.insert({
...   Name: "Imagine Dragons",
...   Event : [
...   {
... Event : "Liberty State Park, 4th Sept",
... Year : 2019,
... Genre : "Rock"
...   },
...   {
... Event : " Jersey City, 6th Oct",
... Year : 2019,
... Genre : " Rock"
...   }
...   ]
...   });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
> db.bands.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f451f2381e1a04eb0cac008"), "Name" : "Imagine Dragons", "Event" : [ { "Event" : "Liberty State Park, 4th Sept", "Year" : 2019, "Genre" : "Rock" }, { "Event" : " Jersey City, 6th Oct", "Year" : 2019, "Genre" : " Rock" } ] }
> db.bands.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f451f2381e1a04eb0cac008"),
        "Name" : "Imagine Dragons",
        "Event" : [
                {
                        "Event" : "Liberty State Park, 4th Sept",
                        "Year" : 2019,
                        "Genre" : "Rock"
                },
                {
                        "Event" : " Jersey City, 6th Oct",
                        "Year" : 2019,
                        "Genre" : " Rock"
                }
        ]
}
>
```